# One versus One and One versus All multiclass classification using logistic regression in python

Tags: python, regression, logistic-regression, multiclass-classification

This is my understanding of OvO versus OvA:
One versus One is binary classification like Banana versus Orange. One versus All/Rest classification turns it into multiple different binary classification problems.
My implementation in python for these 2 strategies yield very similar results :

**OvA**:

```
model = LogisticRegression(random_state=0, multi_class='ovr', solver='lbfgs')
model.fit(x,y)
model.predict(x)
```

**OvO**:

```
    model = LogisticRegression()
    model.fit(x,y)
    model.predict(x)
```

I wanted to confirm my understanding and implementation is correct since I get similar results.
I need to implement OvO and OvA strategy for multiclass classification using logistic regression

Comment: The default value for Logistic Regression parameter **multi_class** is **'ovr'**. So when you're implementing OvO, by default the model uses 'ovr' .

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the sklearn inbuilt class for oneVsRestClassifier and OneVsOneclassifier